# How can I checkout a specific revision of my svn codebase using git svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to checkout a specific revsion of my svn codebase.
Normally, to checkout, I just type
`git svn clone svn+ssh://path_to_codebase`. I need to checkout an older version of the codebase. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `git svn clone` it as usual and then use the usual tools -- `git checkout` can give you access in a "floating" way or create a new git branch at your desired point.

You can also use `git svn init` (note it behaves slightly differently than `git init`) and then `git svn fetch -r XXX` to fetch a specific revision.  This is much faster if the repository is large, but a future `git svn fetch` will fetch the rest of the revs (but never any earlier revs).

Answer (score 11):

I used the following and I obtained an older revision.

```
git checkout `git svn find-rev revision_number`
```

Does anyone have any comments about this?